# Java - Add List Of Objects Inside JSON Array

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson

I have a `list` of `option` class, I want a way to convert the all option inside list into Json and add them to the array inside the simple Json file below.

I'm using `play` framework, So I have to use its Json library.

I have read the file and get the `options` node after loop over all nodes by:

`jsonNode.get("options")`

and it is return an object of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`

this an explain code:

```
List<Option> options = new ArrayList<>();
```

Option class:

```
public class Option {
    private String key;
    private String query;
    private String display;
}
```

Json File:

```
    "options": [
        {
            "key": "...",
            "query": "...",
            "display": "..."
        },
        {
            "key": "...",
            "query": "...",
            "display": "..."
        },...
    ]
```

It is just i can't figure a way to add all `option` from the `List` inside the Json file tag `options`, Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I have get all `options` by:

```
    List<FacetOption> nodeOptions = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("options"), List.class);
```

Then, add all new `option` list to current node list:

```
    nodeOptions.addAll(options);
```

Then, replace old node inside `JsonNode`:

```
    ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
    objectNode.replace("options", Json.toJson(nodeOptions));
```

Finally, write the new file I need:

```
mapper.writeValue(new File(newJsonFilePath), rootNode);
```